# javascript and VB.net returning incorrect results

Tags: javascript, vb.net, .net-2.0

We are noticing this occurs BOTH in javascript and in VB.net 2.0.  So basically both  in server side and client side code.

Basically if you run this equation 975328 - 153279.43 you get the following answer 822048.57000000007.

However, if you run 975328 - 153279.4, 975328 - 153279.433, or 975328 - 153279.5 everything is returned correctly.

Any ideas has to WHY the system calcuates the 975328 - 153279.43 with an answer with 11 decimal places? Not to mention adding the 7 in the 11th decimal place, thus making the equation answer incorrect.

Of course I know I can trim, set the answer to appropiate decimal places, etc., etc., but we are more interested to know WHY it returns such an answer.

Bare in mind, the above is proven by just entering the equation into the immidiate window, thus ellimnating varibables such as object types, etc., etc.

Thanks for the help,
Ken

Comment: What data type did you use in VB? This can make a large difference

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: +1 Because it's not fair to downvote with no comment. I'm guessing downvote may be because it's a beginner's question - that would be unfair if it were the case.

Comment: @Pondidum Question does say the "immidiate" window was used. Presumably CrewChief did something like `?  975328 - 153279.43` so the data types of the constants are determined implicitly: they will be `Integer` or `Double` depending on whether they contain a decimal point.

Answer (score 5):

For the same reason you can't accurately express 1/3 as a decimal (base 10).  You may enter your numbers in base 10, but all the arithmetic happens in base 2 (binary).  So that base 10 value must first be converted to base 2, and you likely end up needing more bits to represent it than are used for the standard double type, if it's even possible to accurately represent number in binary at all.

Another common number to investigate for this error is .1.  When converted to binary, any decimal number with .1 repeats forever after the decimal point.  Thus, there's no way to accurately express the value in binary.

In VB.Net, you at least have the Decimal type you can use handle this kind of thing. IT's much, *much* slower, but it should accurately handle this kind of calculation.  I'm not sure the javascript solution is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware that floating point numbers will only have a fixed precision. You cannot correctly display all numbers via floating point, so some calculations can cause this imprecision to "surface"

A floating point number is presented as an "int" + a bitshift...

Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Internal representationFloating-point numbers are typically packed into a computer datum as the sign bit, the exponent field, and the significand (mantissa), from left to right. For the IEEE 754 binary formats they are apportioned as follows:

```
Type Sign Exponent Significand Total bits Exponent bias Bits precision 

Half   1    5          10           16              15          11 
(IEEE 754-2008)

Single 1    8          23           32             127          24 

Double 1   11          52           64            1023          53 

Quad   1   15         112          128           16383         113
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses float datatype to store those values, and in summary, float data type does not store exact number in memory.  Usually, its best to **use integers** to perform calculations and then you can always **divide by 100.0** to cast to whatever decimal point you wish.  Alternatively you can use **toFixed(DECIMAL_PLACES)** on the object to round it to the decimal point you wish.

Comment: Using integers is bad. They have the nasty habit of truncating the mantissa, which can be significant.